# Type safety in functional interfaces of Java

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I have reached the limit of my ability to deal with Java's type system. The scenario is this:

I have the need for a method that can take a `Collection<Comparable>` and a function that takes a `Collection<Comparable>` as an input and returns a single element from that collection.

That seems to be done like this:

```
private <T extends Comparable<T>> Comparable<T> applyFunctionOnStuff(
        final Collection<Comparable<T>> stuff,
        final Function<Collection<Comparable<T>>, Comparable<T>> function) {
    return function.apply(stuff);
}
```

But then I have the inability to bend `Collections::max` to be a valid input for the function. I was wondering whether there is a way for me to wrap static methods like that into a `Function` class and use them inside this method.

Comment: Can you give an example of exactly how this will be used?  The return type looks off to me, but there might be something I'm not seeing.

Comment: Why `Comparable<T>` everywhere else? Just use `T` as an argument. `T` is already bounded by `Comparable<T>`. That's the type you want your `Collection` and `Function` to work with.

Comment: Yeah, I somehow managed to get it working just now :D Sorry about that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a bit of redundancy in your code as your Type `T` is defined as `T extends Comparable<T>` and then everytime you refer to your type `T` you use it as follows: `Comparable<T>` which should actually be just `T` itself.

So your code should look like this:

```
private <T extends Comparable<T>> T applyFunctionOnStuff(
    final Collection<T> stuff,
    final Function<Collection<T>, T> function) {
    return function.apply(stuff);
}
```

Then you can use `Collections::max` without any further errors

Answer (score 2):

I think it's fine if you accept your own answer, but I'd like to point out that `Comparable` must usually be declared as `Comparable<? super T>` or you'll end up with generic type weirdness.  Your return type should be T, not `Comparable<T>`.

I also still don't see how what you're doing is easier than just calling the function in question directly.  Your method appears to obfuscate the code more than necessary.

```
public class FunctionalComparable {
   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      Collection<String> names = new ArrayList<>( Arrays.asList( 
              "Larry", "Moe", "Curly" ) );

      // why not just this?
      System.out.println( Collections.max( names ) );

      // this seems more work than necessary
      System.out.println( doIt( names, Collections::max ) );
   }

   private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T doIt(
           final Collection<T> collection, 
           final Function<Collection<T>, T> function ) 
   {
      return function.apply( collection );
   }
}
```

Comment: `Collection<String> names = Arrays.asList("Larry", "Moe", "Curly" );`; no need for `new ArrayList` here…

Comment: @Holger Well, I did want an actual ArrayList here.  `asList()` returns something else, which doesn't actually implement all list functions.  It's a habit, but sometimes saves debugging weird exceptions.

Comment: Well, it’s as easy as recalling that the list returned by `Arrays.asList` is not resizable. Deciding beforehand, whether and which modifications are intended for a list, can save you much harder debugging session, where you had to retrace data inconsistencies rather than exception that tell you precisely what’s going on. I sometimes do it the other way round, `Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(…))`, to be sure to notice when my assumption that I don’t need a mutable list does not hold. But unlike stuffing it into an `ArrayList`, the unmodifiable wrapper does perform a copy operation…

Answer (score -3):

Fixed it:

```
private <T extends Comparable<T>> Comparable<T> applyFunctionOnStuff(
        final Collection<T> stuff,
        final Function<Collection<T>, T> function) {
    return function.apply(stuff);
}
```

That seems to magically take an input like `applyFunctionOnStuff(new ArrayList<Integer>(), Collections::max);`

Comment: I don't see why this is better than just calling `Collections.max()` directly, but if you're happy, that works I guess.

Comment: in fact, this solution does not work as inteded, because you're loosing information. indeed it *does* compile but the output is not the `Integer` but only a `Comparable` of `Integer` which is **not** the same

Comment: Yeah, after trying to implement I realised it was basically useless

Comment: You should be able to delete this answer if you realized it is incorrect.

Comment: There is a reference to it in another answer, and it is not incorrect, it just lacks any explanation. I'll keep it around and soak in the shame of giving a crappy answer